# using different version of python with idle windows7-64bit

Tags: python, windows-7-x64, python-idle

I have Python 3.2 and python 1.5.2 installed on my system
(windows 7 64bit)

i can run only IDLE which installed with python version 3.2
IDLE for 1.5.2 is not compatible with 64bit systems

i need to test some code specially for version 1.5.2
how can i make IDLE to use 1.5.2 interpreter instead of 3.2

or any other way to test python 1.5.2 scripts without idle

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run your script with a given interpreter from command line (cmd.exe)

```
c:\path\to\python1.5.2\python.exe your_python_script.py
```

Comment: Thanks bpgergo , haven't thought about that

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Python Launcher for Windows](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher/src/tip/Doc/launcher.rst) to run easily `your_python_script.py` using different Python version.

Also pylauncher allows you to indicate in the script what Python version it expects (in the `#!`-line (shebang)) and run it automatically.

Comment: pylauncher appears to be a prototype implementation of [PEP 397](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) which was Accepted as Standards Track way back in 2011. Do you know why the launcher still isn't being distributed with Python for Windows or why there's still only Vinay Sajip's prototype implementation?

Comment: @martineau: 1. [the docs say that it *is* included (in Python 3.3)](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-397-python-launcher-for-windows) 2. [Vinay Sajip's implementation is *the* implementation used in Python 3.3](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/4b42d7f288c5/PC/launcher.c#l2) (you can [install pylauncher separately](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher/downloads) without installing Python 3.3).